# ODI 12c LKM in mapping without IKM

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-data-integrator

in ODI 12c LKM is used in a mapping in order to load the data from the source to the staging area, but i do not need an IKM which to inset the data from the staging to the target, can ODI mapping do the first phase only that is the LKM pahse, as doing the 2 KM in my case doubles the time.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible but you'd need to use LKM that is written that way.
I don't think there is one OOB there but you should be able to easily write your own.

The main thing there is in the java bean shell code (see [A. Substitution API Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/develop-km/odiref_reference.htm)) you would need to change the call from Collection Table:

```
…INTO TABLE <%=snpRef.getTable("L", "COLL_NAME", "W")%>
```

to Target Table:

```
…INTO TABLE <%=snpRef.getTable("L", "TARG_NAME", "A")%>
```

That's the main thing. You would also need to adjust the fields etc… The post here [ODI - Load data directly from the Source to the Target without creating any Temporary table](https://knowepmbi.wordpress.com/2014/08/28/odi-load-data-directly-from-the-source-to-the-target-without-creating-any-temporary-table/) describes steps in more details, but once you get the idea how powerful API is you can pretty much do anything.